# short names for extjs classes and namespaces

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

i have something like

```
Ext.define('HS.controller.Utility', {
  statics : {
    state : 'Oklahoma'
     }
  });
```

Now i want to access it from my controllers, but in every method of controller, i have to write `HS.controller.Utility.state` to access it. currently i'm doing this : `var ut = HS.controller.Utility` and then accessing `state` as `ut.state`, but again, i've to declare this variable in every function. Is there a way to set it to a short name once in my controller and then access from all functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could do it, the best of which:

```
// Becomes a global variable
var X = Ext.define('My.long.class.Name');

// Set a reference on your main NS at launch time
launch: function() {
    MyApp.X = My.long.class.Name;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to go outside MVC, is there a way to set such variable for each class?

Comment: What do you mean "outside MVC"? If you're that worried about it, type out the full class name!

Comment: it is good to avoid global methods and variables as much as possible. Definitely if there is no solution then i've to use global, but before that if there is any way to declare it inside class where i'm using it for all methods of class, then it'll b great

Comment: There is no difference. If you have a "short name", you need to declare something somewhere. If you don't want to pollute the global namespace then use the second method.

Answer (score 2):

Even easier than the current answer is to just declare an `alternateClassName` with no namespace. Only one line of code, no initialization or race conditions, built into ExtJs.

```
Ext.define('HS.controller.Utility', {

   //
   // Non-namespaced alternate class name will create 
   // 'globally defined' Utility object.
   //
   alternateClassName: 'Utility',

   statics : {
         state : 'Oklahoma'
      }
   });
});
```